# I get stray '#' in program error when I try to compile this program

Tags: c, parallel-processing, openmp, pragma, preprocessor-directive

When I try to compile using `-fopenmp` flag, I get the below error:

> stray `#` in program

Below is my code:

```
#include<omp.h> 
int main()

{        #pragma omp parallel 
     {
     int id=0;
     printf("hello(%d) ",id);
     printf("world(%d)\n",id);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.10/p2, "Preprocessing directives" (*emphasis mine*)

> A *preprocessing directive* consists of a sequence of preprocessing tokens that satisfies the
>   following constraints: The first token in the sequence is a `#` preprocessing token that (at
>   the start of translation phase 4) is **either the first character in the source file** (optionally
>   after white space containing no new-line characters) **or that follows white space
>   containing at least one new-line character**. The last token in the sequence is the first newline
>   character that follows the first token in the sequence.

So, you cannot have a `#` after any other *token*. In your code

```
 int main()
 {        #pragma omp parallel
 ^        ^^^
```

the syntax violates the constraints, hence the error. You have to put it in its *own* line.

Comment: @JeremyP Right, let me be explicit. Thanks

Comment: I only mention it because I spent a couple of minutes not noticing it and thinking "what's he talking about, there is nothing wrong with the `#include`" :)

Comment: @JeremyP You are very correct to point out, sir, what may be apparent to someone, might be very confusing to others in some context. Moreover, it never hurts to be explicit about almost anything, specifically SO answers. :) Thanks for the review and comments. :)